# Add category image before post title on homepage

Tags: categories, images

I am building an football news site, and on my homepage I have a list of the latest articles. Just the titles and date, no featured images etc. Very clean and simple. But I want to add an image from which category it is in front of it.

For example, if it's news from the English football competition, there will be an English flag before the title. In my WordPress article it will be posted in the English category. If it's in the Dutch competition, there will be a Dutch flag etc.

I have an example, made with photoshop. The first 5 articles are how I actually want it, the last are how they are currently. (It's a demo text so don't focus on the text):

[image]

```
Class Block_28_View extends BlockViewAbstract
{
    public function set_content_setting_option()
    {
        $this->options['show_date'] = '';
        $this->options['date_format'] = 'default';
        $this->options['date_format_custom'] = 'Y/m/d';
        $this->options['excerpt_length'] = 20;
    }

    public function render_block($post, $attr)
    {
        $date = $attr['show_date'] ? $this->post_meta_2($post)  : "";

        $output =
            "<article " . jnews_post_class("jeg_post jeg_pl_xs_4", $post->ID) . ">
                <div class=\"jeg_postblock_content\"><img src="\
                    <h3 class=\"jeg_post_title\">
                        <a href=\"" . get_the_permalink($post) . "\">" . get_the_title($post) . "</a>
                    </h3>
                    " . $date . "
                </div>
            </article>";

        return $output;
    }

    public function build_column($results, $attr)
    {
        $first_block  = '';
        $ads_position = $this->random_ads_position(sizeof($results));

        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++ ) 
        {
            if ( $i == $ads_position ) 
            {
                $first_block .= $this->render_module_ads('jeg_ajax_loaded anim_' . $i);
            }

            $first_block .= $this->render_block($results[$i], $attr);
        }

        $show_border = $attr['show_border'] ? 'show_border' : '';

        $output =
            "<div class=\"jeg_posts {$show_border}\">
                <div class=\"jeg_postsmall jeg_load_more_flag\">
                    {$first_block}
                </div>
            </div>";

        return $output;
    }

    public function build_column_alt($results, $attr)
    {
        $first_block  = '';
        $ads_position = $this->random_ads_position(sizeof($results));

        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++ ) 
        {
            if ( $i == $ads_position ) 
            {
                $first_block .= $this->render_module_ads('jeg_ajax_loaded anim_' . $i);
            }

            $first_block .= $this->render_block($results[$i], $attr);
        }

        $output = $first_block;

        return $output;
    }


    public function render_output($attr, $column_class)
    {
        $results    = $this->build_query($attr);
        $navigation = $this->render_navigation($attr, $results['next'], $results['prev'], $results['total_page']);

        if(!empty($results['result'])) {
            $content = $this->render_column($results['result'], $attr);
        } else {
            $content = $this->empty_content();
        }

        return
            "<div class=\"jeg_block_container\">
                {$this->get_content_before($attr)}
                {$content}
                {$this->get_content_after($attr)}
            </div>
            <div class=\"jeg_block_navigation\">
                {$this->get_navigation_before($attr)}
                {$navigation}
                {$this->get_navigation_after($attr)}
            </div>";
    }

    public function render_column($result, $attr)
    {
        $content = $this->build_column($result, $attr);

        return $content;
    }

    public function render_column_alt($result, $attr)
    {
        $content = $this->build_column_alt($result, $attr);

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using a [filter on the title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title), which you can add to your `functions.php`. Like this:

```
add_filter ('the_title', 'wpse305812_add_flag', 10, 2);
function wpse305812_add_flag ($title, $id) {
  if (in_category ('england', $id)) $flag = "http://www.example.com/.../england.jpg"
  elseif (in_category ('brasil', $id)) $flag = "http://www.example.com/.../brasil.jpg"
  ...;
  return '<img src="' . $flag . '"> ' . $title;
  }
```

Note that this (fairly unelegant) code will not take into account the possibility of two flags assigned to one title.

Comment: If I added this my website stopped working. Like I already said, i'm not that great with programming. Can you help me some more?

Comment: Did you just copy/paste the whole block into your site? That wouldn't work. You'd have to adapt it for your actual categories and images.

Comment: I did that, but still doesn't work. It shows a blank page.

Comment: that probably means there's a mistake in your php and you'll need to debug it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the category ID in the loop by using

```
global $post
$cat_id = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Then you can get the thumbnail url of the category by

```
$cat_thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($cat_id);
```

Now you can use this URL to display your image. Additionally, you can pass size parameter to  get_the_post_thumbnail_url().

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really down with php. Where do I put what?

    public function render_block($post, $attr)
    {
        $date = $attr['show_date'] ? $this->post_meta_2($post)  : "";

        $output =
            "<article " . jnews_post_class("jeg_post jeg_pl_xs_4", $post->ID) . ">
                <div class=\"jeg_postblock_content\">
                    <h3 class=\"jeg_post_title\">
                        <a href=\"" . get_the_permalink($post) . "\">" . get_the_title($post) . "</a>

This is the part where it should be. (Before the h3 class)

Comment: I can try to help you if you send the complete function render_block in proper formatted way. you can edit your question and add the snippet with proper formatting.

Comment: so you can use my snippet in this function, $cat_id = get_the_category( $post->ID ); will help you in getting the category ID, you can write both lines before $output = "<article and then you can use $cat_thumb_url variable in the html tag and it'd render the featured image of  category.

Comment: I can't seem it to get it working. Can't you post the full snippet so I can copy and paste it?